# WooCommerce Add to Cart is adding a quantity of 3 to my cart whenever the page is refreshed?

Tags: ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using WooCommerce on my site, and we're using the "add to cart" button. When the add to cart button is clicked the first time, a quantity of 1 is added to the cart, as expected. If I then refresh the page, the quantity increases to 4 - where are those extra three products coming from? Likewise, if I add a product and then click through to the cart itself, an additional 3 products are being added.  What might be causing this?

Thanks for any help!

Posting here the add-to-cart.php code that the Salient theme uses (we've created a child theme but are not overriding this piece):

```
 *
 * @see         http://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     2.5.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
exit;
}

global $product;

echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link',
sprintf( '<a rel="nofollow" href="%s" data-quantity="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" class="%s add_to_cart_button">%s</a>',
    esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ),
    esc_attr( isset( $quantity ) ? $quantity : 1 ),
    esc_attr( $product->id ),
    esc_attr( $product->get_sku() ),
    esc_attr( isset( $class ) ? $class : 'button' ),
    esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() )
),
$product );
```

Comment: Do you have any code to share?

Comment: I can post the add-to-cart code that is part of the salient theme - we're using a child of salient, and have not changed this from the parent theme:

Comment: Any additional code you can share would be helpful

Comment: Ugh, I hate that theme. Unfortunately you haven't given us enough information to help you. First try to isolate the problem. Disable other plugins, temporarily switch WooCommerce to template debug mode (WooCommerce->System Settings->Tools->Enable Template Debug Mode) to only use default templates, and disable the theme as a last resort.